# Short email reply

Tags: politeness, email, formality

Is it polite reply for email?

> Dear xxx, Thank you for your prompt reply. Best regards, xxx

Or is it too short?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation, of course. Some folks get swamped with email, contending with more than 40 or 50 messages in a single day. If the recipient is a busy person, sometimes it's best not to clutter their inbox.

If the situation warrants an acknowledgment, however, yours is fine, although I might suggest:

> Thank you for replying so promptly.

This is minor and subtle, but I think my version is thanking the person for their *promptness*, while yours is thanking them for their *reply*. They already know they've replied, so I think my wording has a little more value to the recipient – but that's a debatable point, given that the wordings are so similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not "too short" in many situations. Most people do not even acknowledge the receipt of an email in this way.

Actually sending a short thank you is something that more people should do.

**However** it might be too short, if the prompt reply you got was something in which the writer has obviously invested a lot of time: if you ask a short question and you get back a 5 page detailed response with sources and attachments, I would suggest you reply with a bit longer "thank you"-mail, acknowledging that effort.

If it was a short answer to a simple question, this is fine. I once got very friendly with a sysadmin because I was the only one that said thank you. Emails went like this:

> Hi X. Could you please install YY and ZZ on AA?
>
> Done
>
> Tnx

So, it can always be shorter :)

Comment: I just received my reply, and I think I must write "thank you" mail to her. Or I shouldn't reply for the email?

Comment: Yes, better to say thank you than not! So, sure, send that thank you. The mail you wrote is fin e:)